# android studio could not open cp proj class cache for build

Tags: android, android-studio

when I try to run my project, Android Studio display this error:
"android studio could not open cp_proj class cache for build.".
I have tried to delete cache files into .gradle but not work.
Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Browse to the cache folder there would be two folders namely, cp_proj, and proj.
Inside both there would be cashes-properties.lock file. Delete that and done.